# Android - Check if Runnable is running

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, service

I want to check if either the Runnable is alive or not in my service. Is there a way i could do this?

```
private Runnable sendData = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            superToast.show();
            screenOn();
            vibrate();
            mHandler.postDelayed(sendData, time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can create a boolean variable and check its value whether it is running or not

```
boolean isRunning = false;

private Runnable sendData = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            isRunning = true;
            superToast.show();
            screenOn();
            vibrate();
            mHandler.postDelayed(sendData, time);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
};
```

and now check for isRunning, if its true it is running else not running

Comment: if anyone is using this to run something on another thread, mark the boolean as volatile

Comment: you should set ```isRunning = false``` in the ```finally{ }```

Comment: @HarryQ as you see, there is a `mHandler.postDelayed();` at the end of `try{ }`, which means this method keeps running periodically. So if we put `isRunning = false` in `finally{ }`, after the first time method runs when the `isRunning` is `false`!

Comment: @AliKhaleqiYekta it depends on the definition of ```isRunning``` variable. My understanding is the runnable is running while the thread is in the try block, once it exits, ```isRunning=false```. Consider this, if the delay time in ```mHandler.postDelayed(sendData, time);``` is very large. There is a period in which all the statements in the current try block complete, and the delayed runnable is yet to start. In such a period, ```isRunnable``` should be ```false``` in my understanding.