# How to know which specific runnable has died in my threadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

I am running a fixed amount of threads using `newFixedThreadPool()` and need to be able to

1. know when one of the runnables has died, and
2. know which specific runnable was the one that died.

One solution for this was by wrapping the Runnables with as a Thread object and calling on `isAlive()`. The Threads ran as they should have, but since `aThread.start()` was never called by the executor always returned `false` which is of no use to me. I considered the possibility of having the Runnables trigger a flag at the beginning of the `run()` function just like [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487754/android-check-if-runnable-is-running) suggested. What would be the best way to keep track of the Runnables that have died? Because my intention is to submit a thread to the executor that that would essentially do the same thing as the one that died.

Comment: Or these runnables supposed to run indefinitely? Or are they 1 shot tasks?

Comment: they run infinitely until `shutdown` is called by the executor

Comment: Essentially, the executor service manages the threads, period. Users managing threads has been a problem since threads were invented. I maintain a threads manager and wrote this article years ago. Perhaps it can help you: http://coopsoft.com/ar/j2searticle.html

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the documentation that @vk3105 provided I had an idea. I ended up looking at [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) and implemented `Future future = executorService.submit(aRunnable)` so that i can check if that runnable was terminated or not by using `future.isDone()` or if the Runnable was cancelled before it was completed `future.isCancelled()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can you use Thread.getState().

And here is a state diagram for threads. [http://bighai.com/ppjava/?p=144](https://web.archive.org/web/20181122174139/http://bighai.com:80/ppjava/?p=144)

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState())

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)

Comment: I would be able to do it if I was using `Thread`, but im using `Runnable`. `getState` cannot be accessed  by a Runnable.

Comment: Please read this link http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-determine-if-a-thread-is-alive-or-not.html